# Show WooCommerce Variable Product Options

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a query that displays products and some information about them.

I am stuck on showing their variable product options (they will all be variable products). After this I have to create an add to cart button that will add to cart, produce a success or error message, and let the user continue shopping. Once there is something in the user's cart I would like to then display a checkout button that will take them to the checkout page.

Here is what I've got so far

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        // Indicate the product category - in this case "training"
        'product_cat' => 'training'
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            // Show the product Featured Image and gallery images
            woocommerce_show_product_images();

            // Show the product Title
            echo the_title();

            // Show the product Custom Fields
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Description', true);
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Specifications', true);
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Video', true);

            // Show the Product Price
            echo $product->get_price_html();

            // Show the Variable Product options, for example: Color, Size etc 
            // stuck here!

            // Show the Add to cart button  
            // stuck here!

            // Show the Checkout button if there is an item in the users cart
            // stuck here!

        endwhile;
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Does anyone know the functions I should be using to display this information?
I'm having a hard time finding anything about it in the documentation / on google.

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Low and behold.. The solution was so simple.
All I had to have inside the loop was:

```
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
```

Now my loop looks like this

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            // Indicate the product category - in this case "Training"
            'product_cat' => 'training'
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );

            endwhile;
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Works fine, and to style the product info I simply created child version of:
 - content-single-product.php
 - product-images.php
 - variable.php
 - meta.php
 - product-thumbnails.php
and edited til' my heart was content.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce by default comes with the variable product option. FOr this you will first have to create attributes. You can create global if all products have same attributes or can create attributes for each product individually.

**Here is a screenshot of a website i am working for**. We have 4 different packages. So my attribute is "packages", and we have 4 packages in it. 
[image]

Once the attributes are saved goto the next tab called **'variations'**. Choose packages attribute and it will automatically load all the variations. Here is another screenshot. You will have to choose a default variation.
[image]

Once all the above changes are made you can then click on any variation and change the product parameters like price, image etc.
[image]

Variations can be used on products like shirts, where you can have different colored shirts and although the price will be same for the shirts but you can give user the ability to choose colors and see how the shirt looks like in that color.

Although woocommerce have setup everything by default but if you are changing the default wordpress template, then the best way to do is to copy the templates folder from woocommerce and place this folder in your active theme under the name of woocommerce, so it would be something like, wp-content/themes/theme-name/woocommerce. And inside these you need all the files and folders that were in the templates folder of the woocommerce. Woocommerce will automatically pick all these files and will serve it. This method is recommended by woocommerce as making direct changes to the plugins will loose all your customizations on the next plugin update.

**EDIT For your situation** : Sorry i think i got carried away :p. Anyways it depends on the situtation you are in and the file that you are using to get these values but, the code below will output all the product variations and all the attributes within that variation. I haven't tested it out, might need minor adjustments. **

```
global $product, $post;
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
    echo 'variation ID'.$value['variation_id'];
    foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
       echo $attr_key.': '.$attr_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful information, but just not helpful for my situation haha! Unfortunately this doesn't relate to my question which should be read carefully - "Does anyone know the functions I should be using to display this information?" I've already made all of my variable products, I've already given them attributes and variations. How do i get and or show the variable product options in my query? I don't want to use the template files when a query will work fine.

Comment: Yes it definitely seems to ouput something! but I'll need to figure out how to make it output a form so that the user can pick what variation they want :S I didn't anticipate this sort of challenge and it's made my question appear quite broad.

Comment: Well you will have to style it yourself according to your needs. But the main thing is to get all the attributes in place. Just var_dump the variables instead of foreach and you will get what ever attributes there are. Then you can sort out all the attributes and just use the ones that you need. I hope it helps.

Comment: sorry Omar but I don't quite understand how you would format it yourself, could you give one example that I can rinse and repeat?

Comment: Well woocommerce just provides basic style for its own layout. If you have a different layout then you have to customize the woocommerce template files that you have copied in your theme. Its preety simple for the most part you can just style it through css. If you have to add some new parts in then you have to first find the file that you want to make changes in. Woocommerce have named all the files properly so just open the file add your html/php and thats it. I get a feeling that you are new to this, i would suggest you go with a plugin like http://www.csshero.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Comment: Again, helpful information, but not related! I don't need to know how to style the information it produces, using chrome debugger to achieve this is easy for me. I need to know how to format it to function like a form so that the user can select which variations they want then an add to cart button for when they are done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75683/discussion-between-mikey-musch-and-omer-farooq).

Comment: Well mikey you can do what ever you can with a normal php application. Goto product variation file. Add a new form with select element. Loop through the variables (code i shared). Add out put them. When someone clicks on the buy(submit btn), grab the elements and add them to basket. simple as that. You can use this link to add a certain attribute/variation product to cart. 
http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=123&variation_id=456&attribute_pa_colour=black. CHeckout this link for more details http://www.remicorson.com/add-woocommerce-variable-product-with-variations-to-cart/

Answer (score 0):

I used some of Omer Farooq's code. Thank you Omer! This will give you a full dropdown menu of the attribute of your choice. In this case, I am using pa_color. I have also removed duplicates so that it will only return the set of colors. This should be used inside of a product loop. In my case, I am using WP_Query to query products.

```
<?php   
 /* Check if this is a variable product */                   
 if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) { ?>
   <select name="pa_color"><?php 

 global $product, $post;

 $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

 $allcolors = array();

 foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {

   /* Get Name (Label) from Attribute Slug */
   $taxonomy = 'pa_color'; /* Change to whatever you want */
   $meta = get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, true);
   $term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, $taxonomy);

    /* Only Return pa_color attributes - Change to whatever you want */
   if ($attr_key == 'attribute_pa_color') {

       $color = $attr_value; 

       /* Checking for duplicates and removing them */
       if( ! in_array( $color, $allcolors ) ) {

         echo '<option value="' . $attr_value . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';

         $allcolors[] = $attr_value; /* Array value to use to check for duplicates */
       }

   } 
 } 
} 
?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```